# ps show column name

Tags: linux, ps

Using these ps options I cut 10 lines and order output of ps by cpu usage (pcpu):

```
ps -eo pcpu,etime,pid,user,args --no-headers| sort -t. -nk1,2 -k4,4 -r |head -n 10
```

I need also show the name of columns (like same commands without cutting the output).

```
%CPU     ELAPSED   PID USER     COMMAND
 0.0 10-23:41:11     1 root     init [2]  
 0.0 10-23:41:11     2 root     [kthreadd]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
ps -eo pcpu,etime,pid,user,args --sort=-%cpu | head -11
```

Comment: It should probably be `head -11` if he wants the top 10 processes.

Answer (score 1):

This works on Centos 7.
Two separate ps commands.
First ps command to get the headers.
Then a semicolon.
Then the second ps command with your specific grep.
The headers used are my standard ones.

```
ps -eo user,pid,ppid,lstart,etime,cmd |head -1;ps -eo user,pid,ppid,lstart,etime,cmd | grep <whatever you are grepping for |grep -v grep
```

Let's break it down with each part on a separate line.

```
ps -eo user,pid,ppid,lstart,etime,cmd |head -1
;
ps -eo user,pid,ppid,lstart,etime,cmd 
| grep <whatever you are grepping for>
| grep -v grep
```

Actual output:

```
[root@myserver ~]# ps -eo user,pid,ppid,lstart,etime,cmd |head -1;ps -eo user,pid,ppid,lstart,etime,cmd |grep sshd |grep -v grep

USER        PID   PPID                  STARTED     ELAPSED CMD
root       4673      1 Tue May 17 09:05:14 2022 122-09:29:11 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root     233733   4673 Tue Sep 13 15:12:12 2022  3-03:22:13 sshd: kbanyas [priv]
kbanyas  234288 233733 Tue Sep 13 15:12:21 2022  3-03:22:04 sshd: kbanyas@pts/0
```